# Append a QByteArray to QDataStream?

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray, qdatastream

I have to populate a `QByteArray` with different data. So I'm using the `QDataStream`.

```
QByteArray buffer;
QDataStream stream(&buffer, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

qint8 dataHex= 0x04;
qint8 dataChar = 'V';

stream << dataHex<< dataChar;
qDebug() << buffer.toHex();  // "0456"  This is what I want
```

However, I would also like to append a QByteArray to the `buffer`.

```
QByteArray buffer;
QDataStream stream(&buffer, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

qint8 dataHex= 0x04;
qint8 dataChar = 'V';
QByteArray moreData = QByteArray::fromHex("ff");

stream << dataHex<< dataChar << moreData.data(); // char * QByteArray::data ()
qDebug() << buffer.toHex();  // "045600000002ff00"  I would like "0456ff"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

when a `char*` is appended it assumes `\0` termination and serializes with `writeBytes` which also writes out the size first (as uint32)

[`writeBytes`' doc:](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatastream.html#writeBytes)

> Writes the length specifier len and the buffer s to the stream and
>   returns a reference to the stream.
>
> The len is serialized as a quint32, followed by len bytes from s. Note
>   that the data is not encoded.

you can use `writeRawData` to circumvent it:

```
stream << dataHex<< dataChar;
stream.writeRawData(moreData.data(), moreDate.size());
```

Answer (score 3):

The 00000002 is the size of the char array, which is written to the stream.

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is, `QDataStream` is *not* raw data. It has its own simple serialization format. It is most suitable for use cases where data is both written (serialized) and read back (deserialized) with `QDataStream`, and using a reliable `QIODevice` (`QBuffer` or `QFile` for example).

If you want to add raw data to a `QBuffer`, you could use a suitable overload of [`write` method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write). But then you might as well just append to the `QByteArray` directly.