# Is It possible to exchange QVector via UDP?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qvector, qudpsocket

I would like to send via a QUdpSocket 2 or 3 QVector :

- One QVector < bool >
- One QVector < int >
- One QVector < float >

Is it possible to do that, and if so how to do it ?

Comment: [Serialize it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: I did somthing like this (just same) , you can send QVector too.
[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538601/converting-qimage-to-qbytearray-using-qdatastream/62632893#62632893)

Answer (score 3):

From Qt documentation:

> The Qt container classes can also be serialized to a QDataStream. These include QList, QLinkedList, QVector, QSet, QHash, and QMap. The stream operators are declared as non-members of the classes.

You can do it using 'QDataStream' like so:

```
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QDataStream out(&buffer);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_6);
out << m_your_data;
out.device()->seek(0);
if(!write(buffer.data()))
{
    // handle your error
}
buffer.close();
```

Comment: you can use [QByteArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271029/append-a-qbytearray-to-qdatastream) as buffer and then write out with [QUdpSocket::writeDatagram](http://www.qtforum.org/article/34385/qudpsocket-broadcast-example.html) it accepts QByteArray as input.. maybe it can be done with the QBuffer as well.. I am lazy to write my own answer..