# Converting QImage to QByteArray using QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qbytearray, qdatastream

Im trying to convert a QImage that maked from ScreenShot  to a QByteArray for sending via QTCPSocket.
when i convert QImage to QByteArray and before sending it i try to deserialize and show it on label it cant !
what's my mistake? thx for helping.

```
QByteArray ImClientShooter::toQByteArray(QImage &img)
{
    QByteArray temp;
    QDataStream data(&temp, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    data « img;
    return temp;
}
QByteArray goOn{toQByteArray(sampleQImage)};     //sampleQImage is a QImage Object
lbl->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage( (QImage::fromData(goOn))));  // QLabel* lbl
```

sampleQImage maked from ScreenShot:

```
QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->grabWindow(0).toImage();
```

Comment: QDataStream adds its own header etc. Use QImage::save with a QBuffer was QIODevice, or QImageWriter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mission passed :D

sender:

```
QImage img;
QByteArray *ba;
bool flag{1};
QDataStream out(ba,QIODevice::ReadWrite);
out << img << flag;
```

receiver:

```
bool flag;
QByteArray ba;
QDataStream in(ba);
QImage temp;
in >> temp >> flag;
    if(flag)
    {
        // got correct data
    }
```

Comment: You don't initialize `QByteArray *ba;`